# Google Apps Marketplace CustomerLicense returns UNLICENSED even after installation

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

This ask is related to the release of the "non-admin can install an app on a domain" feature announced here: http://googleforwork.blogspot.com/2014/09/google-apps-marketplace-to.html

I'm seeing that when a non-admin installs our app onto their domain (through the use of a whitelist), the CustomerLicense returned from the "https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/customerLicense/" endpoint is still UNLICENSED.  When an admin installs the app, the CustomerLicense is set correctly to ACTIVE.

Seems like a bug.  If not, can someone from the GAM team help clarify what I should expect here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

non-admin installs the app only for himself/herself. Since CustomerLicense api is for querying domain level licensing info, the api correctly returns UNLICENSED.

Try using UserLicense api instead https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/userLicense.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks for the pointer!  For anyone else that hits this, here are the following scenarios + states you can get into with this.  (1) Non-admin install: UserLicense == ACTIVE, CustomerLicense == UNLICENSED
(2) Non-admin install followed by admin install: UserLicense == ACTIVE, CustomerLicense == ACTIVE
(3) Admin install: UserLicense == UNLICENSED, CustomerLicense == ACTIVE (Note: Admin install followed by non-admin install isn't possible from the marketplace.)