# How to check if a customer from Google domain installed our app?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We're developing an app that will be published in G Suite Marketplace.

I know that both domain owners and regular Google account holders can install the application from there.

However, the [customer license](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/v2/reference/customerLicense/get) resource from the Marketplace API doesn't accept Gmail addresses, rather only domain names.

So my question is: how to know if `example@gmail.com` did install our application in G Suite Marketplace?

Thank you!

Comment: @noogui, no, it is not. This question is about GSuite Marketplace, it's not Play Market :)

Comment: This question was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790390/google-apps-marketplace-customerlicense-returns-unlicensed-even-after-installati

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Marketplace CustomerLicense returns UNLICENSED even after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790390/google-apps-marketplace-customerlicense-returns-unlicensed-even-after-installati)