# Possible to detect when a user uninstalls a Google Apps Script Add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

Is it possible to detect if a user uninstalls or removes a Google Apps Script (Gmail Add-on)?

I can't find anything in the docs (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail#methods)

My use case is that I want to log data to analytics so I know when a user has removed the plugin to revoke access for other application areas.

Comment: I think that the Marketplace API might help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Marketplace API userLicense resource](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest/v2/userLicense#UserLicense), there was a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790390/google-apps-marketplace-customerlicense-returns-unlicensed-even-after-installati) that may give you an idea of how the API returns responses based on the license status.

The only issue that I found with this API is that it will only return the status of the license added to the user, meaning that showing when it was deleted won't be displayed.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)